# Доступ к методам из конструктора копирования

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор

```
class symb {
private:
   int A;
public:
   symb() {}
   symb(const symb &X) {
      X.show();
   }
   void show() {
      cout << "123";
   }
};

void main() {
symb C;
symb B = C;
}
```

Компилятор строку 7 подчёркивает красным и пишет:

> error C2662: void symb::show(void): невозможно преобразовать указатель "this" из "const symb" в "symb &" 
>   error C2662: void symb::show(void): невозможно преобразовать указатель "this" из "const symb" в "symb &"
>   объект содержит квалификаторы типа, несовместимые с членом функцию "symb ::show" тип объекта: const symb

Почему нельзя получить доступ к функции `show()` объекта `C` из конструктора копирования?

И ещё: почему из функции `main` нельзя получить доступ к переменной `A` объекта `C` (что логично, она ведь `private`), а из конструктора копирования, который вызывается для объекта `B` - можно?

Answer (score 0):

По константной ссылке доступны только константные версии функций-членов. Объявите `show` с `const`:

```
void show() const { ...
```

`private` члены доступны для всех объектов текущего типа, а не только для того, на который указывает `this`. Иначе бы вообще нельзя было скопировать приватные поля одного объекта в другой.

Answer (score 0):

Да все можно. Просто как вы объявили `show`? Как неконстантную, т.е. изменяющую состояние объекта, для которого она вызвана. О объект, для которого вызываете - как константный...

```
void show() const {
    cout << "123";
}
```

и будет все нормально...

> *почему из функции main нельзя получить доступ к переменной A объекта C*

Потому что доступ выявляется на уровне функции. Функция `main` не является ни функцией-членом `symb`, ни дружественной классу `symb`. А конструктор класса *является* таким членом...

Answer (score 0):

> невозможно преобразовать указатель "this" из "const symb" в "symb &"

У вас метод A::show() не объявлен как константный, значит по константному указателю его вызывать нельзя, о чем и говорит компилятор.

> И ещё …

Ключевым словом private помечается поле не объекта а класса. Любой метод класса имеет доступ ко всем приватным полям этого класса. В том числе и других экземпляров.

Answer (score -2):

**Во втором конструкторе (в аргументе функции) нет типа данных.**

```
const symb &x;
```

например на:

```
const int symb &x;
```

Comment: `symb` - это тип.